# How to make a random but partial shuffle in Python?

Tags: python, string, random, shuffle

Instead of a complete `shuffle`, I am looking for a **partial** `shuffle` function in python.

**Example :** "string" must give rise to "stnrig", but not "nrsgit"

It would be better if I can define a specific "percentage" of characters that have to be rearranged.

Purpose is to test string comparison algorithms. I want to determine the "percentage of shuffle" beyond which an(my) algorithm will mark two (shuffled) strings as completely different.

**Update :**

Here is my code. Improvements are welcome !

```
import random

percent_to_shuffle = int(raw_input("Give the percent value to shuffle : "))
to_shuffle = list(raw_input("Give the string to be shuffled : "))

num_of_chars_to_shuffle = int((len(to_shuffle)*percent_to_shuffle)/100)

for i in range(0,num_of_chars_to_shuffle):
    x=random.randint(0,(len(to_shuffle)-1))
    y=random.randint(0,(len(to_shuffle)-1))
    z=to_shuffle[x]
    to_shuffle[x]=to_shuffle[y]
    to_shuffle[y]=z

print ''.join(to_shuffle)
```

Comment: the problem with your shuffling code is that you could end up with less shuffled characters than desired if there is a sequence of swaps that makes a cycle...

Comment: yes, it is quite possible for small strings. I think my code is biased towards speed rather than accuracy.

Comment: a few other tips: why are you incrementing `i` at the end of the loop? it should not have any effect (I think it's a leftover from a `while` version); swapping is more idiomatic in Python with tuple deconstruction rather than using intermediate variables.

Comment: yes, i=i+1 is of not necessary. Could you please elaborate on 'tuple deconstruction' ?

Comment: of course, it's as simple as `a, b = b, a`, you can see it in @jsbueno answer for example... by the way, the exact name was "tuple unpacking" http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is tricky, because there are some edge cases to think about:

- Strings with repeated characters (i.e. how would you shuffle "aaaab"?)
- How do you measure chained character swaps or re arranging blocks?

In any case, the metric defined to shuffle strings up to a certain percentage is likely to be the same you are using in your algorithm to see how close they are.

My code to shuffle `n` characters:

```
import random
def shuffle_n(s, n):
  idx = range(len(s))
  random.shuffle(idx)
  idx = idx[:n]
  mapping = dict((idx[i], idx[i-1]) for i in range(n))
  return ''.join(s[mapping.get(x,x)] for x in range(len(s)))
```

Basically chooses `n` positions to swap at random, and then exchanges each of them with the next in the list... This way it ensures that no inverse swaps are generated and exactly `n` characters are swapped (if there are characters repeated, bad luck).

Explained run with 'string', 3 as input:

```
idx is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
we shuffle it, now it is [5, 3, 1, 4, 0, 2]
we take just the first 3 elements, now it is [5, 3, 1]
those are the characters that we are going to swap
s t r i n g
  ^   ^   ^
t (1) will be i (3)
i (3) will be g (5)
g (5) will be t (1)
the rest will remain unchanged
so we get 'sirgnt'
```

The bad thing about this method is that it does not generate all the possible variations, for example, it could not make 'gnrits' from 'string'. This could be fixed by making partitions of the indices to be shuffled, like this:

```
import random

def randparts(l):
    n = len(l)
    s = random.randint(0, n-1) + 1
    if s >= 2 and n - s >= 2: # the split makes two valid parts
        yield l[:s]
        for p in randparts(l[s:]):
            yield p
    else: # the split would make a single cycle
        yield l

def shuffle_n(s, n):
    idx = range(len(s))
    random.shuffle(idx)
    mapping = dict((x[i], x[i-1])
        for i in range(len(x))
        for x in randparts(idx[:n]))
    return ''.join(s[mapping.get(x,x)] for x in range(len(s)))
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem simpler than it looks. And the language has the right tools not to stay between you and the idea,as usual:

```
import random

def pashuffle(string, perc=10):
    data = list(string)
    for index, letter in enumerate(data):
        if random.randrange(0, 100) < perc/2:
            new_index = random.randrange(0, len(data))
            data[index], data[new_index] = data[new_index], data[index]
    return "".join(data)
```

Comment: And how can it shuffle the whole string with `perc=50`?

Comment: or does it? and what about the "/2" placed there?

Comment: The task is to shuffle some percentage of the string, not with some given probability. But ok, you solve the task, your code is clean, no need of arguing here.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

def partial_shuffle(a, part=0.5):
    # which characters are to be shuffled:
    idx_todo = random.sample(xrange(len(a)), int(len(a) * part))

    # what are the new positions of these to-be-shuffled characters:
    idx_target = idx_todo[:]
    random.shuffle(idx_target)

    # map all "normal" character positions {0:0, 1:1, 2:2, ...}
    mapper = dict((i, i) for i in xrange(len(a)))

    # update with all shuffles in the string: {old_pos:new_pos, old_pos:new_pos, ...}
    mapper.update(zip(idx_todo, idx_target))

    # use mapper to modify the string:
    return ''.join(a[mapper[i]] for i in xrange(len(a)))

for i in xrange(5):
    print partial_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 0.2)
```

prints

```
abcdefghljkvmnopqrstuxwiyz
ajcdefghitklmnopqrsbuvwxyz
abcdefhwijklmnopqrsguvtxyz
aecdubghijklmnopqrstwvfxyz
abjdefgcitklmnopqrshuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe like so:

```
>>> s = 'string'
>>> shufflethis = list(s[2:])
>>> random.shuffle(shufflethis)
>>> s[:2]+''.join(shufflethis)
'stingr'
```

Taking from fortran's idea, i'm adding this to collection. It's pretty fast:

```
def partial_shuffle(st, p=20):
    p = int(round(p/100.0*len(st)))

    idx = range(len(s))
    sample = random.sample(idx, p)

    res=str()
    samptrav = 1

    for i in range(len(st)):
        if i in sample:
            res += st[sample[-samptrav]]
            samptrav += 1
            continue
        res += st[i]

    return res
```

Comment: This will shuffle same part of the string every time.

Answer (score 0):

Evil and using a deprecated API:

```
import random
# adjust constant to taste
# 0 -> no effect, 0.5 -> completely shuffled, 1.0 -> reversed
# Of course this assumes your input is already sorted ;)
''.join(sorted(
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    cmp = lambda a, b: cmp(a, b) * (-1 if random.random() < 0.2 else 1)
))
```

Comment: Funny, but is it guaranteed to finish always? If the compare function is inconsistent I think there could be a sequence of sorting steps that could loop forever (depending on the algorithm used, quicksort should be immune to this for example).